# Rewind ListBox made with jSON & jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, listbox

I have a listbox that's populated by jQuery & JSON like this:

```
$(function(){
  $.getJSON("jsonulmeu.php", function(j){
    var options = 'Selectati valoare';
    for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
      options += '<option selected value="' + j[i].idx + '">' + j[i].txt + '</option>';
    }
    $("select#listbox").html(options);
  });
});
```

When it displays the pointer is at the last row in list. How can I "rewind", and make the listbox start with the first value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function(){
$.getJSON("jsonulmeu.php", function(j){
  var options = 'Selectati valoare';
  for (var i = j.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    options += '<option selected value="' + j[i].idx + '">' + j[i].txt + '</option>';
  }
  $("select#listbox").html(options);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getJSON("jsonulmeu.php", function(data){
    var selectBox = $("select#listbox").empty();
    for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
     selectBox.prepend('<option selected value="' + j[i].idx + '">' + j[i].txt + '</option>');
    }
    selectBox.prepend('Selectati valoare');
});
```

I would really suggest using [jquery templates](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/) for this though.

Comment: wouuu! thank you! I'm the first time on stackoverflow! I'm so impressed about how fast you answer to my issue! :)

Comment: Solved! Change jSON Order By Descending! Thank you!